# c++ getline loop str

Tags: c++, string, loops

I have this c++ code. I want to read two text files called `hasil_eta.txt` and `hasil_T.txt`, then store them into one file, called `eta_T.txt`.

In the file that I was read is a multiple line in 1 column. I want to join two text files and store them in one file.

here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "rwparams.h"

using namespace std;

string IntToStr(int n){
  stringstream result;
  result << n;
  return result.str();
}

int main(){
    ifstream f5;//read eta 
    ifstream f6;//read T 
    ofstream f7;//store it into file
    string hasil_eta;//menampilkan hasil untuk eta
    string hasil_T;//menampilkan hasil untuk T`

    int pengulangan = 170;

    for (int i = 0; i < pengulangan; i++){
        f5.open("hasil_eta.txt");
        getline(f5, hasil_eta);

        f6.open("hasil_T.txt");
        getline(f5, hasil_T);

        f7.open("eta_T.txt");
        f7 << hasil_eta.c_str();
        f7 << " ";
        f7 << hasil_T.c_str();
        f7 << endl;

        f7.close();
        f6.close();
        f5.close();
    }
}
```

My question is how to make a loop to read a file.

Comment: You may use a while loop and detect when you read the end of the file. I would suggest clarifying whether you want to save the lines in the new file with the contents mixed line by line or one file at the beginning and the other at the end.

Comment: _"My question is how to make a loop to read a file."_ That's exceedingly basic and extremely well covered in existing research material. Can you tell us why you haven't used it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're repeatedly reopening the files, so you keep reading the first lines in the inputs over and over, and truncating the output file.
(There's also a minor bug where you read from `f5` instead of `f6`.)

Open the files outside the loop, or specify the file at initialisation: `ifstream f5("hasil_eta.txt");`.
Remove the `close` calls; the destructor handles that for you.
Also remove the `c_str()`s, they are unnecessary.

```
int main(){
    ifstream f5("hasil_eta.txt");
    ifstream f6("hasil_T.txt");
    ofstream f7("eta_T.txt");
    int pengulangan = 170;
    for (int i = 0; i < pengulangan; i++){
       string hasil_eta;
       string hasil_T;
       getline(f5, hasil_eta);
       getline(f6, hasil_T);
       f7 << hasil_eta;
       f7 << " ";
       f7 << hasil_T;
       f7 << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to intersperse lines from two files into one, then you probably want something like

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int,char**){
  std::ifstream e("hasil_eta.txt");
  std::ifstream t("hasil_T.txt");
  std::ofstream et("eta_T.txt");
  for( std::string e_line, t_line;
       std::getline(e, e_line) && std::getline(t, t_line); )
    et
      << e_line << std::endl
      << t_line << std::endl
      ;
  return 0;
}
```

The above code will loop n times where n is the quantity of lines in the shortest file.